# android studio null value in entry: packageOutputFile=null

Tags: android, gradle

after a suddenly shut down my android studio project doesn't run correctly and the null entry error comes with the cradle

```
 null value in entry: packageOutputFile=null
```

would anyone please help me to solve this awseome problem

thanx and more

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This maybe a gradle bug. Delete the gradle folder in the root directory of your application. Then open the app, let the studio rebuild the gradle again.

Answer (score 0):

It's a gradle problem.

Follow these steps :

1. Close the studio, goto the application directory and delete the build.gradle folder.
2. Open the studio and wait for some time and your problem might have been solved.